# Switching between landscape and portrait mode using wpf in tablet devices

Tags: c#, wpf

How could we arrange the controls on a WPF window so that it would automatically align the controls while switching between view modes occur ie between landscape and portrait mode.

```
<Window x:Class="Custom_Track_Reports.LoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="LoginWindow" >
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
<Grid Background="#FF58B0DF" Height="401">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF0F3F4" Height="173" Margin="45,197,58,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" />
        <Image Height="125" Margin="340,10,330,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Images/logo_lrg.png"/>
        <Label Content="Custom Track Reports" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.607,1.112" Width="268" Height="47" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="26" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBox Margin="128,0,0,110" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="25" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="21" Text="" Name="userTextBox" FontStretch="Expanded" Opacity="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="546" AcceptsReturn="False" KeyDown="userTextBox_KeyDown" />
        <Button x:Name="enterButton" Content="Enter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,311,166,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Height="26" FontSize="14" Style="{DynamicResource button}" Click="enterButton_Click"/>
        <Label Content="User ID" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,215,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Googled wpf portrait landscape and this was the first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323318/wpf-orientation

Comment: i found that .. it describes how to detect the motion but what i want to know is how to implement the transformation..