# WPF detect reverse landscape orientation

Tags: wpf, tablet, screen-orientation

I knew how to [detect general orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323318/wpf-orientation), such as Portrait or Landscape, but is there a way to know if current orientation is Left-Portrait or Right-Portrait, Landscape or Reverse Landscape?

I need to know about the reverse orientation because in my video recording app, the live preview window looked weird when the device was rotated.

Comment: May be you will have to consume some event like `OrientationChanged`.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage but where can I find the object that publishes such event? Window or UserControl does not.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage I mentioned in the question (which lead to that link you posted anyway) that such approach doesn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact orientation, you can listen to the `DisplaySettingsChanged` event as mentioned in your link. Then you can retrieve the `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ScreenOrientation` enum parameter. It can have one of the [following values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screenorientation?view=netcore-3.1):

- Angle0
- Angle90
- Angle180
- Angle270

Te be able to use this in WPF, you'll need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`.

```
private int GetOrientation()
{
    return ((int) System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation) * 90;
}
```