# Disable screen rotation

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1, .net-4.5, tablet

I'm building a WPF application that needs to run on a Windows 8.1 (NOT PHONE) tablet.
Is there a way to programmatically **prevent \ disable** the application from rotating when the user rotates the device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323318/wpf-orientation)

Comment: @Ray I've read this question but no one answered it. they provide a way to tell when the rotation takes place but not how to disable it.

Comment: The question is duplicate, but the duplicate question has no accepted answer, possibly the answer is NO then...?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal the proposed duplicate doesn't mention the target OS of the tablet and the .net framework the application is built on. this question is also from November 2011.

Comment: Detect that the rotation has occurred, and then apply a RotateTransform on your layout to move things back to the orientation you want. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323318/wpf-orientation