# Desktop orientation changes and keep content not orientating with desktop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When my desktop orientation changes the content I call in XAML rotates with the orientation I would like to keep this content not orientating with the desktop.

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas">
    <Image Source="{}pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/Background.png" Height="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=ActualWidth}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323318/wpf-orientation)

Comment: Thanks I was hoping for just XAML resolution.